# Clearing Text value by Javascript Executor and Actions are NOT working!- Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm

Im trying to clear the Existing value of a field[TextBox]by the folowing ways,

1. Action - MoveToElement - Keys.Backspace
2. Selenium method - Clear()

everytime: used to get the same error message :No such elementexception though the element identification is correct and even i tried to focus the element before performing the action but still failed.

suggest me the approach please

note: Microsoft.Dynamics CRM application

Comment: please post a snippet of your HTML including the element which you are trying to clear. Is the element contained within a frame or iframe?

Comment: No such element == you have wrong locator.

Comment: @VladimirEfimov It's possible the locator is correct but the element is inside a frame, iframe document. If it's inside a frame or iframe, the driver needs to be moved to the frame document for it to be able to find the element.

Comment: @RyanWilson yep, good addition makes sense... but anyway stan says that he was able to "focus" an element whetever that means... probably 'focus' it via browser inspector.

Comment: @VladimirEfimov Yeah, I'm not sure either. Have to wait until Stan gives us some more information.

Comment: its inside the table. Im able not able to focus on the element using Actions.

Comment: is there any way to clear a value inside Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM application ?

Comment: when i enter the value for the first time - selenium ables to identify the element BUT when i access the same element for clearing the value - selenium fails to locate it and throws the error! @RyanWilson

Comment: @VladimirEfimov ++

Comment: @stan Post your code where you are getting the element and setting it's value the first time as well as your code for clearing it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on additional data from comments here is what probably happens:

1. You get an instance of `WebElement` - *there is an element matching your `locator` at that moment of time*
2. You enter some value to the element - *this action most likely changes your web element somehow (e.g. changes style/class/or even a tag)*
3. You trying to get an instance of the **same** `WebElement` using the **same** `locator` and NoSuchElementException is thrown - *this is because the element is now **not exactly the same** as in step 1*

If you add sample HTML *before entering* text and *after the text is entered* we probably will be able to provide the exact solution.

As of now I can suggest 2 ways:

1. When you want to clear the text - you need to use different locator. That will match exactly the element you need to work with.
2. If your page does not reload after you type text, you just can create a variable for `WebElement`, find element and store it to the variable before entering the text, then work with this variable enter a text using `sendKeys`, then clear text applying `clear` method to this same variable. I.e. it might be that you don't really need to call `findElement` twice if the page stays the same.

Comment: problem is focus is not on the element. driver was referring another page after switching to the current page i was able get the handle of webelement.